# Do I need a backend server as a mediator when using GCM, if I don't have any data to store?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Seems like this is what is currently needed :

Client 1 -> backend -> GCM -> Client 2.

But I'm unsure what the backend server would do in my scenario where I don't want to store any data. I just want client to client interaction through GCM this way :

Client 1 -> GCM -> Client 2.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GCM, the sender (usually the backend) needs to have an API key that you get from the Developers Console. This API key is used in every HTTP request sent to the GCM server as a form of authorization to send messages.

The client(s) need to register using a sender ID, which comes from the same project on the Developers Console where you got the API key. This results in a registration token that the client sends to the server/sender. This token is what identifies a client device from other client devices.

The [demo app](https://github.com/google/gcm) actually has a setup somewhat similar to what you wanted: it acts as both a sender and a receiver. This only works easily because we know there will only be one sender and one receiver. The difficulty starts when there are multiple receivers. The sender would need to keep track of all their registration tokens. You would need to inform that one sender of every new registrant's registration token (you need to do this sending outside of GCM- usually through a POST call to the server, which cannot really be done on a device). If the sender has to keep track of a thousand tokens, it will need to persist this on its own.

Take note, the above scenario only applies to a "single sender-multiple receivers/clients" setup. If you need more than one device to have the ability to send, you will need to let that other device keep track of the registration tokens of its receivers as well. This ups the complexity quite a bit.

At the very least, you actually do have data to store: the registration tokens of the devices who will be receiving messages from the sender. However, the sender needs to keep track of responses as well (for debugging and monitoring purposes). Having said all this, while you technically could have your client device act as a server/backend, it puts a lot of work on the device and it is difficult to maintain. I strongly suggest setting up at least a very simple server.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

GCM is designed to send notifications from a backend to a device and vice versa.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

So the following options are viable:

Client 1 -> backend -> GCM -> Client 2. (HTTP)

Client 1 -> GCM -> backend -> GCM -> Client 2. (XMPP)